# jquery change images

Tags: jquery, arrays, image

I have this script:

```
<script>
var images = [
    "webit.png",
    "analog.png",
    "projectica.png"
];

currentImage = 0;

function ChangeImage()
{
    currentImage++;

    if (currentImage > images.length - 1)
        currentImage = 0;
    $("#screenBackImage").css("background-image", "url(images/works/" + images[currentImage] + ")");

    $("#screenImage").fadeOut(500, function() {
        $("#screenImage").attr("src", "images/works/" + images[currentImage]);
        $("#screenImage").fadeIn(500);
    });
    setTimeout(function() {
        ChangeImage();
    }, 5000);
}

ChangeImage();
</script>
```

And when the image change in the first time, it's jump over the second image in the images array, to "projectica.png", and then to the first image in the array and then it's work good (first, second, third and again first..),

Why is this happening?

Comment: What do you mean by "then it's work good"?, and note you are starting with the second image in the array (numeration starts with 0) as you increment at start

Answer (score 2):

You are using second index of array by incrementing the index variable by `currentImage++;` Initializing the currentImage to `-1` will do the trick for your first time problem and you will get zero index (*first element*) by `currentImage++;`

*Change*

```
currentImage = 0;
```

*To*

```
currentImage = -1;
```

You code would be

```
var images = [
    "webit.png",
    "analog.png",
    "projectica.png"
];

currentImage = -1;

function ChangeImage()
{
    currentImage++;

    if (currentImage > images.length - 1)
        currentImage = 0;
    $("#screenBackImage").css("background-image", "url(images/works/" + images[currentImage] + ")");

    $("#screenImage").fadeOut(500, function() {
        $("#screenImage").attr("src", "images/works/" + images[currentImage]);
        $("#screenImage").fadeIn(500);
    });
    setTimeout(function() {
        ChangeImage();
    }, 5000);
}

ChangeImage();
```

Answer (score 1):

I think you should do this:

```
if (currentImage > images.length - 1) currentImage = 0;
$("#screenBackImage").css("background-image", "url(images/works/" + images[currentImage] + ")");

$("#screenImage").fadeOut(500, function () {
    $("#screenImage").attr("src", "images/works/" + images[currentImage]);
    $("#screenImage").fadeIn(500);
});

// Increment the currentImage variable here, not in the begining...
currentImage++;
```

[**DEMO HERE**](http://jsfiddle.net/mZUpp/1/)